# is there any way to split Spark Dataset in given logic

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark

i am looking for Spark Dataset split application which is similar to bellow mentioned logic.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np

>>> df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 4), columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
>>> df1
          a         b         c         d
0 -0.398502 -1.083682  0.850632 -1.443868
1 -2.124333  1.093590 -0.338162 -1.414035
2  0.753560  0.600687 -0.998277 -2.094359
3 -0.635962 -0.291226  0.428961  1.158153
4 -0.900506 -0.545226 -0.448178 -0.567717
5  0.112911  0.351649  0.788940  2.071541
6 -0.358625  0.500367  1.009819 -1.139761
7  1.003608  0.246925  0.225138 -0.586727
8  0.355274 -0.540685  1.482472  0.364989
9  3.089610 -1.415088 -0.072107 -0.203137
>>>

>>> mask = df1.applymap(lambda x: x <-0.7)
>>>
>>> mask
       a      b      c      d
0  False   True  False   True
1   True  False  False   True
2  False  False   True   True
3  False  False  False  False
4   True  False  False  False
5  False  False  False  False
6  False  False  False   True
7  False  False  False  False
8  False  False  False  False
9  False   True  False  False
>>> mask.any(axis=1)
0     True
1     True
2     True
3    False
4     True
5    False
6     True
7    False
8    False
9     True
dtype: bool
>>> df1 = df1[-mask.any(axis=1)]
>>> df1
          a         b         c         d
3 -0.635962 -0.291226  0.428961  1.158153
5  0.112911  0.351649  0.788940  2.071541
7  1.003608  0.246925  0.225138 -0.586727
8  0.355274 -0.540685  1.482472  0.364989
>>>
```

In spark i gone though `df.filter` but its trying pick only matched ,  but in my case i need to filter(remove) data into 3 -4 level. only one level i shown above.  which is kind of filtering.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I Figured out , how it should be filtered, in 3 layers,  all solutions is in `df.except` command.

Assuming bellow mentioned as Data `office_people.csv`

```
+---+------------------+--------------------+--------------------+------+---------------+
| id|         full_name|           job_title|               email|gender|     ip_address|
+---+------------------+--------------------+--------------------+------+---------------+
|  1|   Walter Lawrence|    Graphic Designer|wlawrence0@answer...|  Male| 179.89.185.194|
|  2|     Mark Reynolds| Structural Engineer|  mreynolds1@ihg.com|  Male| 23.192.227.122|
|  3|     Gregory Jones|     Design Engineer|   gjones2@prweb.com|  Male|  75.232.148.42|
|  4|      Ashley Clark|     Staff Scientist|  aclark3@unicef.org|Female| 18.103.212.244|
|  5|    Dorothy Harvey|     Design Engineer|   dharvey4@ucoz.com|Female|  180.119.92.27|
|  6|       Laura Allen|      Tax Accountant|lallen5@shutterfl...|Female|  194.60.142.75|
|  7|    Richard Knight|     Staff Scientist|rknight6@sourcefo...|  Male|   5.25.210.201|
|  8| Gregory Carpenter|Payment Adjustmen...|gcarpenter7@googl...|  Male|  92.16.231.195|
|  9|     Sean Thompson|             Teacher|sthompson8@twitpi...|  Male|    4.216.52.79|
| 10|  Frances Stephens|Human Resources M...|fstephens9@artist...|Female| 181.11.246.116|
| 11|      Louis Little|  Nurse Practicioner|  llittlea@lycos.com|  Male|209.135.198.222|
| 12|     Frances Perry|    Quality Engineer|    fperryb@youtu.be|Female| 173.162.64.208|
| 13|    Russell Hanson|    Web Developer II|rhansonc@wikimedi...|  Male|   57.81.25.130|
| 14|  Michelle Wallace|    Technical Writer|  mwallaced@time.com|Female|    56.17.86.56|
| 15|   Keith Patterson|VP Product Manage...|kpattersone@globo...|  Male| 252.146.42.238|
| 16|   Kathleen Howard|      Programmer III|khowardf@accuweat...|Female| 235.163.98.206|
| 17|Russell Cunningham|        VP Marketing|rcunninghamg@berk...|  Male| 72.197.113.247|
| 18|       Henry Dixon|       Developer III|    hdixonh@fema.gov|  Male| 63.144.255.192|
| 19|    Martha Jackson| Electrical Engineer|mjacksoni@cyberch...|Female|167.209.159.139|
| 20|        Sean Kelly|Systems Administr...|   skellyj@opera.com|  Male|  6.183.241.141|
+---+------------------+--------------------+--------------------+------+---------------+
only showing top 20 rows
```

`Dataset<Row> people_non_Engineer = people.except(people_Engineer);` simply splits `else` part of the filter(Though i Did in JAVA,)

```
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;

import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataTypes;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.Metadata;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructField;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType;

public class starthere {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("Example App");

       JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);

       // SQLContext sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc);

       SparkSession spark = SparkSession
                .builder()
                .appName("Java Spark SQL Example")
                .config("spark.some.config.option", "some-value")
                .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "file:///C:/tmp/") 
                .getOrCreate();

       StructType customSchema = new StructType(new StructField[] {
                new StructField("id", DataTypes.IntegerType, true, Metadata.empty()),
                new StructField("full_name", DataTypes.StringType, true, Metadata.empty()),
                new StructField("job_title", DataTypes.StringType, true, Metadata.empty()),
                new StructField("email", DataTypes.StringType, true, Metadata.empty()),
                new StructField("gender", DataTypes.StringType, true, Metadata.empty()),
                new StructField("ip_address", DataTypes.StringType, true, Metadata.empty())
            });

        Dataset<Row> people  =  spark.read()
                .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
                .schema(customSchema)    
                .option("header", "true")
                .load("office_people.csv");

        people.show();
        Dataset<Row> people_Engineer = people.filter(col("job_title").contains("Engineer"));
        people_Engineer.show();
        Dataset<Row> people_non_Engineer = people.except(people_Engineer);
        people_non_Engineer.show();
        Dataset<Row> people_Sys_Admin = people.filter(col("job_title").contains("Systems Admin"));
        Dataset<Row> people_non_tech = people_non_Engineer.except(people_Sys_Admin);
        people_non_tech.show();
        Dataset<Row> people_Tech_Writer = people.filter(col("job_title").contains("Technical Writer"));
        Dataset<Row> people_non_tech_people = people_non_tech.except(people_Tech_Writer);
        people_non_tech_people.show();
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Preserving order is very difficult in Spark applications due to the assumptions of the RDD abstraction. The best approach you can take is to translate the pandas logic using the Spark api, like I've done here. Unfortunately, I do not think you can apply the same filter criteria to every column, so I had to manually translate the mask into operations on multiple columns. This [Databricks blog post](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/08/12/from-pandas-to-apache-sparks-dataframe.html) is helpful for anyone transitioning from Pandas to Spark.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1000)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 4), columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
mask = df1.applymap(lambda x: x <-0.7)
df2 = df1[-mask.any(axis=1)]
```

The result we want is:

```
          a         b         c         d
1 -0.300797  0.389475 -0.107437 -0.479983
5 -0.334835 -0.099482  0.407192  0.919388
6  0.312118  1.533161 -0.550174 -0.383147
8 -0.326925 -0.045797 -0.304460  1.923010
```

So in Spark, we create the dataframe using the Pandas data frame and use `filter` to get the correct result set:

```
df1_spark = sqlContext.createDataFrame(df1).repartition(10)
df2_spark = df1_spark.filter(\
   (df1_spark.a > -0.7)\
 & (df1_spark.b > -0.7)\
 & (df1_spark.c > -0.7)\
 & (df1_spark.d > -0.7)\
 )
```

Which gives us the proper result (notice the order is not preserved):

```
df2_spark.show()
+-------------------+--------------------+--------------------+-------------------+
|                  a|                   b|                   c|                  d|
+-------------------+--------------------+--------------------+-------------------+
|-0.3348354532115408| -0.0994816980097769| 0.40719210034152314|  0.919387539204449|
| 0.3121180100663634|  1.5331610653579348| -0.5501738650283003|-0.3831474108842978|
|-0.3007966727870205|  0.3894745542873072|-0.10743730169089667|-0.4799830753607686|
| -0.326924675176391|-0.04579718800728687| -0.3044600616968845|  1.923010130400007|
+-------------------+--------------------+--------------------+-------------------+
```

If you ***absolutely needed*** to create the mask using Pandas, you would have to preserve the index of the original Pandas dataframe and remove individual records from the Spark by creating a broadcast variable and filtering based on the index column. Here's an example, YMMV.

Add an index:

```
df1['index_col'] = df1.index

df1
          a         b         c         d  index_col
0 -0.804458  0.320932 -0.025483  0.644324          0
1 -0.300797  0.389475 -0.107437 -0.479983          1
2  0.595036 -0.464668  0.667281 -0.806116          2
3 -1.196070 -0.405960 -0.182377  0.103193          3
4 -0.138422  0.705692  1.271795 -0.986747          4
5 -0.334835 -0.099482  0.407192  0.919388          5
6  0.312118  1.533161 -0.550174 -0.383147          6
7 -0.822941  1.600083 -0.069281  0.083209          7
8 -0.326925 -0.045797 -0.304460  1.923010          8
9 -0.078659 -0.582066 -1.617982  0.867261          9
```

Convert the mask into a Spark broadcast variable:

```
myIdx = sc.broadcast(df2.index.tolist())
```

Create and modify the dataframes using the Spark api:

```
df1_spark.rdd.filter(lambda row: row and row['index_col'] not in myIdx.value).collect()
df2_spark = df1_spark.rdd.filter(lambda row: row and row['index_col'] in myIdx.value).toDF()

df2_spark.show()
+-------------------+--------------------+--------------------+-------------------+---------+
|                  a|                   b|                   c|                  d|index_col|
+-------------------+--------------------+--------------------+-------------------+---------+
|-0.3007966727870205|  0.3894745542873072|-0.10743730169089667|-0.4799830753607686|        1|
|-0.3348354532115408| -0.0994816980097769| 0.40719210034152314|  0.919387539204449|        5|
| 0.3121180100663634|  1.5331610653579348| -0.5501738650283003|-0.3831474108842978|        6|
| -0.326924675176391|-0.04579718800728687| -0.3044600616968845|  1.923010130400007|        8|
+-------------------+--------------------+--------------------+-------------------+---------+
```

Comment: good to see your update @Myles-Baker. i just tried with some better example to solve this puzzle. just have look.